# How to detect if livestreaming is sending any data

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

Is there a way to detect if a livestreaming server is sending data.  I have a webpage with videos that come from different sources with these protocols.

Some videos are from ustream.

```
<embed flashvars="autoplay=false&amp;brand=embed&amp;cid=7975&amp;v3=1" width="100%" height="377" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" id="utv344723" name="utv_n_193353" src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Others are flash video streams that I load into a jwplayer.

```
 <embed
 type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
 id='single2'
 name='single2'     flashvars='file=USen_vbr_450@50104&streamer=rtmp://cp132684.live.edgefcs.net/live/&autostart=true&plugins=false'
 />
```

Others are flash video streams where I must load their own player.

```
 <embed
 type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
 id='single2'
 name='single2'
 src='http://videosite.org/video/jwplayer/player.swf'     flashvars='file=sltviphone.sdp&streamer=rtmpt://saltandlighttv.streamguys.net:80/live&skin=http://saltandlighttv.org/video/jwplayer/skins/modieus/modieus.swf&autostart=true'
 />
```

Others have a different streaming protocol.

```
    <embed id="MediaPlayer2" src="mms://www.streaming.com/video_a" width="100%" height="377" autostart="true" align="top" border="0" filename="mms://www.streaming.com/video" animationatstart="true" transparentatstart="true" showcontrols="1"></embed>
```

Are there ways to detect if the video is streaming without opening a player? I would do this in javascript.